# Using a regular expression to match a div block having a specific Class

Tags: c#, regex

Match a block of div with particular class "report-content"

```
Regex using: /<div\\sclass="\report-content\">(.*?)<\/div>/

<div class="content"></div>

<div class="report-content">
Are you falling sick without any apparent illness? 
Your job could be the reason behind it. Check the list
of jobs that could jeopardize your health and send you to the doctor. 
</div>


<div class="report-content">
Are you falling sick without any apparent illness? 
Your job could be the reason behind it. Check the list
of jobs that could jeopardize your health and send you to the doctor.
</div>
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: `/<div\sclass="report-content">(.*?)<\/div>/`

Comment: probably, you need to set the singleline mode (or dotall mode). As an exercise, try to remove uneeded backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

This works, try it:

```
  /<div class=\"report-content\">(.*?)<\/div>/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine with minor adjustments. Also, you should include the `s` modifier to also match newlines as follows:

`/<div\ class=\"report-content\">(.*?)<\/div>/s`

matches

```
Are you falling sick without any apparent illness? 
Your job could be the reason behind it. Check the list
of jobs that could jeopardize your health and send you to the doctor.
```

Here is a working demo:

http://regex101.com/r/pQ5eS7

Comment: Adding the `s` is correct in PHP (which is what Regex101 is using), but C# doesn't support that notation.  @Rahul, why did you use regex literal syntax in the question?  (That is, why did you put `/` on the ends?)

Answer (score 0):

At first you mixed up `\"` with `"\` next to the class attribute.

Well you did not mention the programming language you are using but I would add the marker to work multiline:

```
/<div class=\"report-content\">(.*?)<\/div>/s
```

In my opinion there is also no reason to use the `\s` so I replaced with a space.